# Switch to an application using its PID

Tags: command-line, x11, window

I'm using Gnome. In vim, I want to map a key to switch to Firefox. I know that I should use bash commands (a command in form of `!...`). Is it possible to switch to an application using its PID?

Comment: So, in X terms, you want to raise and focus a window from a shell?

Comment: You probably need to get the [x window id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151407/how-to-get-an-x11-window-from-a-process-id) from the pid and send a [_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2577229) message afterwards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first two examples will activate the first listed Firefox window, based on its Title.  Firefox always ends its Title-bar with *"Mozilla Firefox"*... "listed" means: as listed by `wmctrl` querying `X`. The first example uses a *fuzzy* match for the title.

```
wmctrl -a "Mozilla Firefox"
```

Or, to get the title more specifically:

```
wmctrl -Fa "$(wmctrl -l | sed -rn 's/^([^ ]+ +){3}(.*Mozilla Firefox)$/\2/p')"
```

---

If you know the `PID` of the process behind a window, you can use this command:

```
wmctrl -ia $(wmctrl -lp | awk -vpid=$PID '$3==pid {print $1; exit}')
```