# Opening a programme in a floating window in i3

Tags: window-manager, i3, window-management

I want to open a programme in a floating window.  I tried
`exec emacsclient -c ; floating enable`, but that made the
window that was active before float, not the new window.

Answer (score 19):

This is how I did it for my Galculator application:

~/.config/i3/config

```
for_window [class="Galculator" instance="galculator"] floating enable
```

To find out what goes in your class="..." and instance="...", type **xprop** in terminal, then click on the window you want to float. You will find the info somewhere on the bottom under WM_CLASS(STRING)="instance", "Class".

Comment: This is fine if we want _all_ windows of that class to float. I usually find that I don't.

Answer (score 7):

The proper way to make the currently focused window float in i3 is to run

```
i3-msg floating enable
```

This is what your config line does.

The problem now is that `i3-msg` runs before the window is in focus (if it even grabs focus). Peter O. explains [over here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45173/17409) how to get a window in focus based on its PID. We can use this as such:

```bash
our_application &
pid="$!"

# Wait for the window to open and grab its window ID
winid=''
while : ; do
    winid="`wmctrl -lp | awk -vpid=$pid '$3==pid {print $1; exit}'`"
    [[ -z "${winid}" ]] || break
done

# Focus the window we found
wmctrl -ia "${winid}"

# Make it float
i3-msg floating enable > /dev/null;

# Move it to the center for good measure
i3-msg move position center > /dev/null;

# Wait for the application to quit
wait "${pid}";
```

**Nota bene:**

- If the application *does* grab focus by itself, it may be sufficient to just wait for that to happen. See [here](https://superuser.com/q/382616/74934) for ways to determine the currently focused window.
- I didn't work through it, but it should be possible to extend the script to return focus to where it was before we changed it.
- `wmctrl` can not always figure out the PID for all windows; ImageMagick's `display` always has PID 0 in its listing, for example. See [here](https://github.com/reitzig/scripts/blob/master/showqr) for modified approach that uses the window title.
- Wrapping the salient parts of above solution in a script, it should be possible to write something like

  ```
  exec our_command; grab_focus; floating enable
  ```

  in the i3 config.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to sum up [HubbleTs post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468905/105615) with some <s>other dirty workarounds</s> added information:

---

**TLDR**: Append `&& i3-msg "[id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)] floating enable"` to your shortcut definition (requires `xdotool`).
E.g. `bindsym $mod+button exec program && i3-msg "[id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)] floating enable"`

---

You can set up rules for *all* windows that match a list of criteria that can be set up within your i3-config or equivalently send using `i3-msg`.

The syntax is `for_window [ criteria ] command`. You can read more about it [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_criteria). If you want it to work only on a single window, you might ensure uniqueness of your criteria.

There is not just

> **class**
>
> > Compares the window class (the second part of WM_CLASS). Use the special value **focused** to match all windows having the same window class as the currently focused window.
>
> **instance**
>
> > Compares the window instance (the first part of WM_CLASS). Use the special value **focused** to match all windows having the same window instance as the currently focused window.

but way more, like `title` or `id`:

> **title**
>
> > Compares the X11 window title (_NET_WM_NAME or WM_NAME as fallback). Use the special value __focused__ to match all windows having the same window title as the currently focused window.
>
> **id**
>
> > Compares the X11 window ID, which you can get via xwininfo for example.

Assuming `emacsclient` to be a command line program, you could hence add

```
for_window [ title="uniquetitle" ] floating enable
```

to your i3 config and open your favorite terminal using

```
termite -e emacsclient -t uniquetitle
```

and it would directly open in floating mode.

If it is not a command line program and has no title options, you could play around with the other criteria or e.g. (using `xdotool` and `i3-msg`):

```
bindsym $mod+button exec program && xdotool getactivewindow set_window --name uniquetitle
```

or less dirty

```
bindsym $mod+t exec program && i3-msg "[id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)] floating enable"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the "&&" waits for the first half (the exec) to complete before it runs the second half (the floating enable on the current window).  What actually happens is that the new program window is opened, and once it's closed the window focus returns to is made floating.  Adding `--no-startup-id` also doesn't solve that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Was searching for a way to have a application always start in tiling but at the same time have a way to open it in floating (without changing all the other instances of this app beeing send to floating).

Combining [Adaephon-R's suggestion from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/40jqad/comment/cywlkq3/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and [Suuuehgi's answer on this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477813) the easiest (and most stable for me) solution I found is using the `WM_CLASS(STRING)` of the window-property and setting the `instance` field by passing the `--class floating` (or similar) parameter to the desired app.

in my `.i3/config`:

```
# start a terminal (alacritty)
bindsym $mod+Return exec --no-startup-id alacritty
# start a terminal in floating mode
bindsym $mod+Shift+Return exec --no-startup-id alacritty --class floating

# enable startup in float from exec by setting the x11 class to floating
# many apps support '--class floating' for setting the x11 class (the instance get renamed)
for_window [class="floating"] floating enabled move position center
```

As the result I can open my terminal-sessions with

- `$mod+Return` while tiling
- `$mod+Shift+Return` while floating

Comment: For `xterm` you need `-class floating`, like `bindsym $mod+Shift+Return exec xterm -class floating`

Answer (score 0):

A small tweak to termnml's answer made it work for me. The full working result now reads:

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+Return exec --no-startup-id urxvt --class floating
for_window [class="floating"] floating enabled
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you want to comment on another answer, please don't post this as an answer - the answer section is only intended for definitive solutions to the original problem. Once you have enough reputation, you will be able to comment on other people's posts. In the meantime, consider submitting an edit suggestion if you think that you can improve the other answer.